# MysQL ignores int value - Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert

I have the weirdest issue with inserting a row into a **MyISAM table**.

```
insert into mytable (id, status, code) values (2534480091, 0, '253448009')
```

**#1062 - Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY'**

Where did it even come to the point that id should insert the id **2147483647** for **2534480091**? Before running this query I have made sure the id is available:

```
select id from mytable where id = 2534480091 limit 1;"
```

Structure

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`code` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
```

Index

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `status` (`status`),
KEY `code` (`code`),
```

I have tried **truncating** the table, **checking** it for errors and **repairing** it. Nothing seems to work.

There is nothing wrong with the PHP code behind it. Passing this query manually in phpMyAdmin shows the exact same error.

What's going on?

Comment: `The number 2,147,483,647 (or hexadecimal 7FFF,FFFF) is the maximum positive value for a 32-bit signed binary integer`

Comment: use long int, the int is too big, so it will only consider the id as the max value for int

Comment: Thanks man, I really thought int(11) meant 11 digits.

Answer (score 2):

2147483647 is the maximum int value. To use a bigger number, you will need to declare it as a bigint.

Comment: Thank you Richard. That explains a lot and solves my problem. :)